# C# and ClosedXML :: How to throw/catch an exception when opening a nonexistent file?

Tags: c#, file, exception, try-catch

I'm a Java coder learning C# for a new project.  I have the following code which opens and reads an Excel spreadsheet:

```
using System.IO;
using ClosedXML.Excel;

public foo(string excelFilePath)
{
    var workbook = new XLWorkbook(new FileStream(excelFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
    // read and write to the file, etc...
}
```

This all works great, but I want the code to gracefully throw an exception if the file is misplaced or misnamed.  Something like this:

```
using System.IO;
using ClosedXML.Excel;

public foo(string excelFilePath)
{
    var workbook = null;
    try
    {
        new XLWorkbook(new FileStream(excelFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
        // read and write to the file, etc...
    }
    catch(Exception ???)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Gah!  I couldn't find \""+excelFilePath+"\"");
    }
}
```

I've searched online, but I can't find any examples of doing this with `new XLWorkbook()`  Did I pick the wrong function?  Thank you.

Comment: Try removing the `???`. It should work. If you want to log the contents of the exception, then use `catch(Exception ex)`, and the exception information will be in the `ex` variable. You might want to use a more specific exception type (I think this will result in an `IOException`) then use `catch(IOException ex)`. That way anything other than what you expect and have programmed will still crash your app

Comment: [Try-Catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-the-try-catch-block-to-catch-exceptions) along with  [FileNotFoundException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filenotfoundexception?view=net-6.0) to catch the specific error and then the [IOException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ioexception?view=net-6.0) to catch all other IO exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would before even be throwing the exception check for the file existence, if there is a problem opening the file you can throw IO exception

```
   if (!File.Exists(excelFilePath))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Gah!  I couldn't find file \"" + excelFilePath + "\"");
            return;
        }
        var workbook = null;
        try
        {
            new XLWorkbook(new FileStream(excelFilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite));
            // read and write to the file, etc...
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Gah!  I can't open file \"" + excelFilePath + "\"");
        }
     }
```